# How to keep packages updated and keep in pace with security updates

Tags: ansible, security

In a project with multiple vms that run various applications from Wordpress to Django and various other things.

Is there a way or a tool to keep track of the packages that require updates or have security problems not on an app level but on a vm level. Do I have to ssh into each machine and keep track of the packages or is there a smarter way to do that, could a tool like ansible be used for this job?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pre-made roles like [this one](https://galaxy.ansible.com/oefenweb/apt) or [this one](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/security) or [this one](https://galaxy.ansible.com/weareinteractive/apt) to manage apt for system related security upgrades.